# issue with regular expression python

Tags: python-2.7

i have 2 line as a command output `sh ip int bri` and i want to fetch all up interfaces. my re expression matching one line which has FastEthernet0/0 but not loopback0. any suggestions please.

```
line
```

'Loopback0              1.1.1.1         YES NVRAM  up                    up'

```
line1
```

'FastEthernet0/0        10.0.0.1        YES NVRAM  up                    up'

```
match=re.search(r'\w+\d+?/?\d+?\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)', line1)

match.group()
```

'FastEthernet0/0        10.0.0.1        YES NVRAM  up                    up'

```
match=re.search(r'\w+\d+?/?\d+?\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)', line)

match.group()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    match.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: You can update re to `r'\w+[\d/]+\s+\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)`

Comment: @Kadir, it worked modified below:-

r'\w+[\d+/]+\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)', line)

any comments about the error on below which did not work:
r'\w+\d+/?\d+?\s+(\d{1,3}\.){3} \d{1,3}\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)',

/?\d+? and [\d/]+ makes the diff

Answer (score 1):

a very verbose version of what you are looking for (with named groups `(?P<name>regex)` for easy access of the matches):

```
import re

re_str = '''
(?P<name>[\w/]+)                            # the name (alphanum + _ + /)
\s+                                         # one or more spaces
(?P<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})  # IP address
\s+                                         # one or more spaces
(?P<yesno>YES|NO)                           # yes (or no?)
\s+                                         # one or more spaces
(?P<type>\w+)                               # type (?)
\s+                                         # one or more spaces
(up|down)                                   # up (or down?)
\s+                                         # one or more spaces
(up|down)                                   # up (or down?)
'''

regex = re.compile(re_str, flags=re.VERBOSE)

text = '''Loopback0 1.1.1.1 YES NVRAM up up
FastEthernet0/0 10.0.0.1 YES NVRAM up up
FastEthernet0/0 10.0.0.1 YES NVRAM up up'''

for line in text.split('\n'):
    match = regex.match(line)
    print(match.group('name'), match.group('IP'))
```

this prints

```
Loopback0 1.1.1.1
FastEthernet0/0 10.0.0.1
FastEthernet0/0 10.0.0.1
```